# Custom brush patttern in flutter custom paint

Tags: flutter, drawing, brush, custom-painting, flutter-custompaint

I have created a drawing application in flutter. Its working very well for simple drawing but the issue is I want to implement ***brush patterns*** in drawing and there is no option for custom brush style/ stroke patterns in **CustomPainter** class. Please any help would be appreciated.

**Thanks**

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.